# plotting results of hierarchical clustering on top of a matrix of data

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, cluster-analysis, dendrogram

How can I plot a dendrogram right on top of a matrix of values, reordered appropriately to reflect the clustering, in Python?  An example is the following figure:

[image]

This is Figure 6 from: [A panel of induced pluripotent stem cells from chimpanzees: a resource for comparative functional genomics](https://elifesciences.org/articles/07103)

I use `scipy.cluster.dendrogram` to make my dendrogram and perform hierarchical clustering on a matrix of data.  How can I then plot the data as a matrix where the rows have been reordered to reflect a clustering induced by the cutting the dendrogram at a particular threshold, and have the dendrogram plotted alongside the matrix?  I know how to plot the dendrogram in `scipy`, but not how to plot the intensity matrix of data with the right scale bar next to it.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The question does not define *matrix* very well: "matrix of values", "matrix of data". I assume that you mean a *distance matrix*. In other words, element D_ij in the symmetric nonnegative N-by-N *distance matrix* D denotes the distance between two feature vectors, x_i and x_j. Is that correct?

If so, then try this (edited June 13, 2010, to reflect two different dendrograms).

**Tested in `python 3.10` and `matplotlib 3.5.1`**

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as sch
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform

# Generate random features and distance matrix.
np.random.seed(200)  # for reproducible data
x = np.random.rand(40)
D = np.zeros([40, 40])
for i in range(40):
    for j in range(40):
        D[i,j] = abs(x[i] - x[j])

condensedD = squareform(D)

# Compute and plot first dendrogram.
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.09, 0.1, 0.2, 0.6])
Y = sch.linkage(condensedD, method='centroid')
Z1 = sch.dendrogram(Y, orientation='left')
ax1.set_xticks([])
ax1.set_yticks([])

# Compute and plot second dendrogram.
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.3, 0.71, 0.6, 0.2])
Y = sch.linkage(condensedD, method='single')
Z2 = sch.dendrogram(Y)
ax2.set_xticks([])
ax2.set_yticks([])

# Plot distance matrix.
axmatrix = fig.add_axes([0.3, 0.1, 0.6, 0.6])
idx1 = Z1['leaves']
idx2 = Z2['leaves']
D = D[idx1,:]
D = D[:,idx2]
im = axmatrix.matshow(D, aspect='auto', origin='lower', cmap=plt.cm.YlGnBu)
axmatrix.set_xticks([])  # remove axis labels
axmatrix.set_yticks([])  # remove axis labels

# Plot colorbar.
axcolor = fig.add_axes([0.91, 0.1, 0.02, 0.6])
plt.colorbar(im, cax=axcolor)
plt.show()
fig.savefig('dendrogram.png')
```

[image]

---

Edit: For different colors, adjust the `cmap` attribute in `imshow`. See the [scipy/matplotlib docs](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps) for examples. That page also describes how to create your own colormap. For convenience, I recommend using a preexisting colormap. In my example, I used `YlGnBu`.

---

Edit: `add_axes` ([see documentation here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/figure_api.html?highlight=add_axes#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes)) accepts a list or tuple: `(left, bottom, width, height)`. For example, `(0.5,0,0.5,1)` adds an `Axes` on the right half of the figure. `(0,0.5,1,0.5)` adds an `Axes` on the top half of the figure.

Most people probably use `add_subplot` for its convenience. I like `add_axes` for its control.

To remove the border, use `add_axes([left,bottom,width,height], frame_on=False)`. [See example here.](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/manual_axis.html)

Answer (score 9):

If in addition to the matrix and dendrogram it is required to show the labels of the elements, the following code can be used, that shows all the labels rotating the x labels and changing the font size to avoid overlapping on the x axis. It requires moving the colorbar to have space for the y labels:

```
axmatrix.set_xticks(range(40))
axmatrix.set_xticklabels(idx1, minor=False)
axmatrix.xaxis.set_label_position('bottom')
axmatrix.xaxis.tick_bottom()

pylab.xticks(rotation=-90, fontsize=8)

axmatrix.set_yticks(range(40))
axmatrix.set_yticklabels(idx2, minor=False)
axmatrix.yaxis.set_label_position('right')
axmatrix.yaxis.tick_right()

axcolor = fig.add_axes([0.94,0.1,0.02,0.6])
```

The result obtained is this (with a different color map):

[image: The result obtained is this:]