# output scipy dendrograms to TreeView files

Tags: python, hierarchical, hierarchical-clustering

I've written a python script using pylab and scipy to output hierarchical cluster heatmaps and dendrograms from an expression matrix based on this post:
[plotting results of hierarchical clustering ontop of a matrix of data in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982929/plotting-results-of-hierarchical-clustering-ontop-of-a-matrix-of-data-in-python)

Now I would like to export my array and gene (column and row) dendrograms to a text files such that the program TreeView can also view this data (e.g., cdt, gtr, atr files). Does anyone have experience with this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't have any experience with it, but http://jtreeview.sourceforge.net/docs/JTVUserManual/ch02s11.html#ch2_file_tr_colheaders describes how the files should look -- just a normal tab delemited. Then it's just a matter of converting the data of the `Z1` in the question you are reffering to in the proper way.

Comment: let me know (here) if you run into problems.