# How to use dendrogram to work with a lot of data

Tags: python, scipy, cluster-analysis

I'm working with python 2.7.9.
I use `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram` to show my clustering result.  [Dendrogram here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram). One problem is that, I have about 200 data. I cannot see clearly their labels.

```
...
z=linkage(dist, method='complete')
R=dendrogram(z, labels=mylabels)
```

[image]

1.I know that `R["ival"]` has the labels corresponding to the leaf nodes, but it's not an easy job to match a value and data in such a dense figure.

2.I think of extracting a part of the data. For example, green links in the left. At this scale the labels can be seen clearly. And I think that's a way with great flexibility to analyze data. But I do not know how to do that.

3.I use `leaf_label_func`. My goal is: when a data really belongs to a class--cups, for example-- show part of its name/label. For example, if one model has a name "cups_b1", then just show "b1". So, at least I can see the locations of  one category of my data one time.

```
def llf(id):
  if id< nmodels:
    mylabel=labels[id]
    if mylabel.find("cups")!=-1:
      index=mylabel.find("_")
      outlabel=mylabel[index+1:]
      return outlabel
    else:
      return ""   #without the else part the function will return None, and that makes the output figure strange
R=dendrogram(z, leaf_label_func=llf, leaf_rotation=90 )
```

But even this, I cannot recognize the labels.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a great method to visually extract small details out of dendrograms.  A couple solutions come to mind.

Work with the cluster data outside of the graph.

```
from collections import defaultdict

clusterdict = defaultdict(list)
for ind,clust in zip(R['leaves'],R['color_list']):
    clusterdict[clust].append(ind)
```

Now you can explore each cluster individually.

```
In [50]:
clusterdict['g']

Out[50]:
[73, 8, 30, 14, 0, 67, 91, 60, 81, 61, 83, 22]
```

Another option would be to print the dendrograms on both axes (x,y) as shown by the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982929/plotting-results-of-hierarchical-clustering-ontop-of-a-matrix-of-data-in-python?rq=1).  Then if you absolutely must see the labels on the graph you can print half the labels on the x axis and half on the y axis.