# Scipy dendrogram with names

Tags: python, scipy, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I'm using the example dendrogram from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982929/plotting-results-of-hierarchical-clustering-ontop-of-a-matrix-of-data-in-python) in my work but would also like to keep track of which row / column is from which piece of data.

I've edited the code with records of names of the data as `names` as follows and would like to print out the names at the bottom and to the right of the distance matrix visualization. I've tried adding `labels = names` in the call to `dendrogram` but this didn't help.

Does anyone know how to add labels to this?

```
import scipy
import pylab
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as sch 

# Generate random features and distance matrix.
x = scipy.rand(40)
D = scipy.zeros([40,40])
for i in range(40):
    for j in range(40):
        D[i,j] = abs(x[i] - x[j])

### new code
names = [ ] 
for i in range(40):
    names.append( 'str%i'%( i ) ) 
    print names[-1]
### end new code

# Compute and plot first dendrogram.
fig = pylab.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.09,0.1,0.2,0.6])
Y = sch.linkage(D, method='centroid')
Z1 = sch.dendrogram(Y, orientation='right')
ax1.set_xticks([])
ax1.set_yticks([])

# Compute and plot second dendrogram.
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.3,0.71,0.6,0.2])
Y = sch.linkage(D, method='single')
Z2 = sch.dendrogram(Y)
ax2.set_xticks([])
ax2.set_yticks([])

# Plot distance matrix.
axmatrix = fig.add_axes([0.3,0.1,0.6,0.6])
idx1 = Z1['leaves']
idx2 = Z2['leaves']
D = D[idx1,:]
D = D[:,idx2]
im = axmatrix.matshow(D, aspect='auto', origin='lower', cmap=pylab.cm.YlGnBu)
axmatrix.set_xticks([])
axmatrix.set_yticks([])

# Plot colorbar.
#axcolor = fig.add_axes([0.91,0.1,0.02,0.6])
#pylab.colorbar(im, cax=axcolor)
fig.show()
fig.savefig('dendrogram.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

The python package [`heatmapcluster`](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/heatmapcluster) (available [on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/heatmapcluster)) that I wrote accepts (in fact, requires) labels.

Here's a simplified version of your script using `heatmapcluster`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from heatmapcluster import heatmapcluster


# Generate random features and distance matrix.
x = np.random.rand(40)
D = np.abs(np.subtract.outer(x, x))

names = ['str%i' % i for i in range(len(x))]

h = heatmapcluster(D, names, names,
                   num_row_clusters=3, num_col_clusters=3,
                   label_fontsize=8,
                   xlabel_rotation=-75,
                   cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm,
                   show_colorbar=True,
                   top_dendrogram=True)

plt.show()
```

And here is the plot it generates:
[image: plot]

(Note that, for a symmetric array like `D`, there is really no point in clustering both axes.  By symmetry, they will generate the same dendrogram.)