# 2 Dendrograms + Heatmap from condensed correlationmatrix with scipy

Tags: python, scipy, cluster-analysis

I try to create something like this:
[plotting results of hierarchical clustering ontop of a matrix of data in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982929/plotting-results-of-hierarchical-clustering-ontop-of-a-matrix-of-data-in-python)

Unfortunatelly when I try to execute the code, I get the following warnings:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\USER1\Desktop\test.py", line 15
    Y = sch.linkage(D, method='centroid')
ClusterWarning: scipy.cluster: The symmetric non-negative hollow observation matrix looks suspiciously like an uncondensed distance matrix

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\USER1\Desktop\test.py", line 22
    Y = sch.linkage(D, method='single')
ClusterWarning: scipy.cluster: The symmetric non-negative hollow observation matrix looks suspiciously like an uncondensed distance matrix
```

In addition, a small window opens but crashes ...

Answer (score 1):

That code that you linked to has a problem: it passes the square distance matrix to [`linkage`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html).  The first argument of `linkage` has been a frequent source of confusion, so in recent versions of scipy, the code generates a warning if something that looks like a square distance matrix is passed in.

You'll have to modify your code to not pass a square distance matrix to `linkage`.  If you already have a such a matrix, you can convert it to the condensed form expected by `linkage` with the function [`scipy.spatial.distance.squareform`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html).

To avoid further confusion, I updated the code in the linked answer so that it passes a condensed distance matrix to `linkage`.

Comment: The warnings are gone, but the window still crashes.